# Is there a way to create a bound function providing it's arguments inside an array?

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have a function like the following.

```
var func = function(a, b, c) {
    console.log(a);
    console.log(b);
    console.log(c);
}
```

And what I want to do is call it by providing it's arguments inside an array like so:

```
func.apply(null, [1, 2, 3]);
```

which works as expected. Now, if I wanted to have that function called asynchronously, for example using a setTimeout, how could I do that? I tried the following:

```
setTimeout(func.bind.apply(null, [null, 1, 2, 3]), 1000);
```

but it gives me an error:

> TypeError: Bind must be called on a function

Is there an elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass arguments to [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Parameters) itself, like this

```
setTimeout(func.bind(null, 1, 2, 3), 1000);
```

[Online Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/thefourtheye/gU7D7/)

The error you are getting is because `bind` will operate only on a function object, so the first argument to `apply` should be the actual function object, like this

```
setTimeout(func.bind.apply(func, [null, 1, 2, 3]), 1000);
```

Comment: That would work if the arguments I want to pass to "func" weren't inside an array. That's why I'm trying to use apply, unsuccessfully so far.

Comment: @hardas That is why I have suggested a way to fix your code in the second part.

Answer (score 3):

There are quite a few ways to do this.

### Method 1: `setTimeout` extra parameters

Did you know that you can pass `setTimeout` extra parameters just like you can do with `call`?

```
setTimeout(func, 1000, 1, 2, 3);
```

However suppose you have an array of arguments instead:

```
setTimeout(func, 1000, [1, 2, 3]); // This will not work
```

So you need to do the following instead:

```
setTimeout(function (args) {
    return func.apply(this, args);
}, 1000, [1, 2, 3]);
```

Unfortunately this won't work in older versions of Internet Explorer. However you could always do this:

```
function applyAsync(f, ms, args) {
    return setTimeout(function () {
        return f.apply(this, args);
    }, ms);
}
```

You call it as follows:

```
applyAsync(func, 1000, [1, 2, 3]);
```

In my opinion this is the cleanest and the fastest solution. However if you want a cleverer solution then:

### Method 2: `bindable`, `callable` and `appliable`

My favourite functions in JavaScript:

```
var bind = Function.prototype.bind;
var call = Function.prototype.call;
var apply = Function.prototype.apply;

var bindable = bind.bind(bind);
var callable = bindable(call);
var appliable = bindable(apply);
```

I won't explain how it works in detail but this is what you need to know:

1. The `bindable` function takes a function `f` and returns a function equivalent to `f.bind`; and `f.bind` is partially applied to any additional parameters.
2. The `callable` function takes a function `f` and returns a function equivalent to `f.call`; and `f.call` is partially applied to any additional parameters.
3. The `appliable` function takes a function `f` and returns a function equivalent to `f.apply`; and `f.apply` is partially applied to any additional parameters.

The function you are looking for is `appliable`:

```
setTimeout(appliable(func, null, [1, 2, 3]), 1000);
```

This is as clever and elegant as it gets.

Comment: Nice :-) For explanations, see [Explain bindbind() function](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13504936/1048572) and [How does bindbind(call) work](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23482982/1048572)

Answer (score 2):

You either want

```
Function.apply.bind(func, null, [1, 2, 3])
```

or

```
Function.bind.apply(func, [null, 1, 2, 3])
```

Currently you're applying `bind` on `null`, not on `func`, which will throw the error.

Instead of accessing `.apply`/`.bind` on `Function`, you could as well use `Function.prototype` or `func`.

Comment: The current context is `window`, not `null`.

Comment: @Guffa: not when it is bound to `null`? I don't understand. The OP does not want to bind to `window` (and in strict mode, you wouldn't anyway).

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean, you are correct. The point that I was trying to make is that the value of `func.bind` is just a reference to `bind`, it has no relation to `func` any more. If called, it would get the global context instead of `func`, but then apply replaces that with `null`.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply `Function.prototype.bind` this way, it just requires you to pass null to the first element of your array and you should be okay.

```
var myFun = function (a,b,c) {
    console.log(a,b,c);
}, myFunBound;

myFunBound = Function.prototype.bind.apply(myFun, [null, 1,2,3]);

setTimeout(myFunBound, 1000);
```

Comment: This works just fine if you remove the parentheses from the end of the statement where you define myFunBound. Thanks :)

Comment: Oh yeah sorry forgot to remove these, on my way.