# Chaining 'bind' and 'call' in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, chaining

When I reading this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9468106/3573327), find `var g = f.call.bind(f);`. I can't understand this with my first sight.

So does it has some direct meaning, and has some appropriate usage scenarios?

And further when you using `call(or apply)` or `bind` or both in chaining, what will happen? Is there some laws?

Comment: Have you tried calling `g` with some arguments and looked how they are accessible in `f`?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24191701/1048572).

Answer (score 4):

> `var g = f.call.bind(f);`. I can't understand this with my first sight.

I assume you're familar with both the [`.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) `Function` methods? Well, it binds the `f.call` method to the function `f`.

Notice that `f.call` is just `Function.prototype.call`, it doesn't matter that we access it as a property on `f` because we don't call it here.

> So does it has some direct meaning?

It might become more obvious when we look at the ES6 equivalent:

```
(Function.prototype.call).bind(f) // or
(f.call).bind(f) // is basically
(...args) => f.call(...args) // or more clear
(ctx, ...args) => f.call(ctx, ...args)
```

> Does it have some appropriate usage scenarios?

Well, now that you know what it does, yes. It can take a prototype method and transforms it to a static function that takes the instance as the first argument. An example:

```
function Example(n) { this.name = n; }
Example.prototype.display = function() { console.log(this.name); }

Example.display = Function.call.bind(Example.prototype.display);

var e = new Example;
e.display(); // is the same as
Example.display(e);
```

> Are there any laws for further chaining `call`/`apply`/`bind`?

Yes: as always, only the last property in the chain is actually called as a method. In the above example, theres no difference between `f.call.bind(…)`, `Function.prototype.call.bind(…)` or `Function.call.apply.bind.call.bind(…)` - it always calls `bind` on `call`.

However, by passing them as arguments to each other, you can do [some](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31075516/1048572) [crazy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13505258/1048572) [things](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23484109/1048572) which are more or less useful.

Answer (score 2):

Good question. Let's start off by considering an example that's come up on StackOverflow before: mapping all the strings in an array to lowercase. Of course I can write

```
strings . map(function(string) { return string.toLowerCase(); })
```

but that seems a bit verbose. I'd rather write

```
strings . map(CALL_LOWERCASE_WITH_ELT_AS_THIS)
```

So I might try

```
strings . map(String.prototype.toLowerCase)
```

or, to use the shorter idiom some prefer

```
strings . map(''.toLowerCase)
```

because `''.toLowerCase` is exactly equal to `String.prototype.toLowerCase`.

But this won't work, of course, because `map` passes each element to the specified function **as its first argument**, not as its `this`. Therefore, we need somehow to specify a function whose first argument is used to call some other function as its `this`. That, of course, is exactly what `Function.call` does:

```
function.call(context)
```

The first argument to `call` ("context") is used as the `this` when calling `function`.

So, problem solved? We ought to be able to just say:

```
strings . map(''.toLowerCase.call)
```

and people have tried this and then wonder why it didn't work. The reason is that even though we are passing `call` of `toLowerCase` as the callback to `map`, `map` still has no idea that the callback is supposed to be called with a `this` of `''.toLowerCase`. We need to explicitly tell `map` which `this` to use to call the function, which in the case of `map` we can do with its second "context" argument:

```
strings . map(''.toLowerCase.call, ''.toLowerCase)
```

Actually, since `call` is the same on any function object, we can simplify this to just

```
strings . map(Function.call, ''.toLowerCase)
```

This works and gets the job done beautifully.

However, whereas `map` provides this second "context" argument to specify the `this` to call the callback with, that is not something we can depend on being available in all situations. We need a more general way to say "make a function which calls `Function.call` with some particular function as `this`".

That is exactly what `bind` does. It says "take a function and make another function which calls it with a particular `this`":

```
function.bind(context)
```

In our case, what we want to do is to "take the function `Function.call` and make another function which calls it with a `this` of `''.toLowerCase`. That is simply

```
Function.call.bind(''.toLowerCase)
```

Now we can pass this to `map` without having to use the second argument:

```
strings . map(Function.call.bind(''.toLowerCase))
```

That works exactly the same as `strings . map(Function.call, ''.toLowerCase)`, because in general `map(fn, ctxt)` is precisely equal to `map(fn.bind(ctxt))`.

The following breaks this down into a readable form, step by step:

```
Function .           // From the Function object
  call .             // take the `call` method
  bind(              // and make a new function which calls it with a 'this' of
    ''.toLowerCase   // `toLowerCase`
  )
```

When this construct is specified as a callback, such as to `map`, it means:

> Invoke `call` with the first argument passed in and `''.toLowerCase` as `this`, which by virtue of the definition of `call`, means to call `toLowerCase` with that argument as `this`.

Some people prefer to simplify this a bit by saying

```
var call = Function.call;
var toLowerCase = ''.toLowerCase;

strings . map(call.bind(toLowerCase))
```

or, using the second argument provided by `map`, just

```
strings . map(call, toLowerCase)
```

which is almost readable as English: "**map** each string to the result of **call**ing **toLowerCase**.

Another common, related use case would be specifying the callback in a `then` on a promise. Consider the following code:

```
promise . then(function(result) { result.frombulate(); })
```

That's fine, but it's a bit verbose. And `then` has no way to pass in a context to be used as `this` when invoking the success or failure handler. But with the above, we can now write:

```
promise . then(call.bind(frombulate))
```

There are other use cases for the `call.bind` idiom, but this is one of the most common ones: define a callback whose effect is to invoke some function with the parameter passed to the callback as its `this`.

With ES6 fat arrow functions, of course, I can write

```
promise . then(result => result.frombulate())
```

so there is relatively less advantage in the shorthand offered by `call.bind(frombulate)`, and it is hard to deny that the fat-arrow version is more readable than that using `bind`.

The following question might be of interest too: [Array.map and lifted functions in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27776631/array-map-and-lifted-functions-in-javascript).

Answer (score -1):

```
m.call.bind(m)
```

can be used as shorthand for:

```
function(x){return m.bind(x)()}
```

The former is the "point-free" form of the latter, 
arguments are implicit. It would be useful with
list-operations like map(), making them shorter.
You can write stuff like:

```
let m   = "".toUpperCase;
let fun = m.call.bind(m);
let see = ['a','b'].map(fun);
```