# Function.call method as callback

Tags: javascript

Excuse me if I've something missed, but when I try to use call method as a callback it gives me strange error in both Chrome and Node.js.

```
['  foo', ' bar  '].map(String.prototype.trim.call);
TypeError: ["  foo", " bar  "].map is not a function
at Array.map (native)
```

But these snippets works:

```
['  foo', ' bar  '].map(function (item) { 
    return String.prototype.trim.call(item);
}); // => ['foo', 'bar']
/*
  and ES2015
*/
['  foo', ' bar  '].map(function () { 
    return String.prototype.trim.call(...arguments);
}); // => ['foo', 'bar']
```

Also I've checked type of `call` function:

```
typeof String.prototype.trim.call; // => 'function'
```

Am I doing something wrong? Could anyone please explain me why I get such error? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution to your problem is to just write it out:

```
['  foo', ' bar  '].map(s => s.trim());
```

If you want to pass a function, you will need something more complicated than you want, along the lines of

```
.map(Function.call.bind(String.prototype.trim))
```

or if you prefer

```
.map(Function.call, String.prototype.trim)
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31198503/chaining-bind-and-call-in-javascript/31204239#31204239) may answer all your issues.

Comment: Thanks for answer. First one with bind gives me the same error as above. Second one works.

Comment: @Ermon: He meant to bind `call` to `trim` :-)

Comment: aside: `['  foo', ' bar  '].map(eval.call, "".trim)` is a short way of saying that.

Comment: @dandavis: Using the `Date` constructor or `eval` function for <s>brevity</s> golfing will confuse the heck out of anyone. If you do that, you should first eliminate all whitespaces :-)

Comment: any rose by the name of `call` smells as sweet... not for prod, but great for console snips...