# What is the use of the following code. What is it supposed to do

Tags: javascript, call, apply, bind

What is the use of this following code and what is the expected behavior.

Using bind call and apply in a very complicated way

```
var test = Function.prototype.call.bind(Function.prototype.bind,Function.prototype.call)
var mapGet = test(Function.prototype.apply);
var arrayIndex = test(Array.prototype.slice);
```

Comment: Related: [Chaining 'bind' and 'call' in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31198503/4642212).

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that this code has been intentionally obfuscated by the author.

`arrayIndex` works the same way as `Array.prototype.slice` does and has the following syntax:

```
arrayIndex(arr, startIndex, [endIndex])
```

`mapGet` is a function that can be called as follows:

```
mapGet(fn, context, arr)
```

it returns the result of calling `fn` with the arguments passed in the array `arr` using the given `context`

```js
var test = Function.prototype.call.bind(Function.prototype.bind,Function.prototype.call)
var mapGet = test(Function.prototype.apply);
var arrayIndex = test(Array.prototype.slice);

console.log(
  arrayIndex([1, 2, 3, 4], 1, 3) // [2, 3]
);

console.log(
  mapGet((x, y) => x + y, null, [10, 20]) //  30
);
```