# Applying prototype function in function composition

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, underscore.js, lodash

I want to understand how to use `_.compose`, and for example turn something like this:

```
url.substr(url.indexOf('?'))
```

into composition, something maybe like:

```
var c = _.compose(String.substr, String.indexOf('?'))
c(url)
```

upd. Sorry for maybe asking really stupid question, but I don't get the way it suppose to work. Why this:

```
c = _.compose('abcd'.indexOf)
c('c')  // returns 5.. wtf?
```

Comment: That's not plain (functor) composition that you want to do there. It's more like an applicative or monad.

Comment: So, you're saying it means exactly what?

Comment: That you cannot use `compose` if the `url` is used twice in that expression.

Comment: I don't get how this thing works... Why for example `c = _.compose('abcd'.indexOf); c('c')` returns 5?

Comment: @Agzam: because 'c' is the fifth letter of "Object"... ;)

Comment: @Agzam: It actually does work in strict mode. In sloppy mode however, that is equivalent to `String.prototype.indexOf.call(window, 'c')` which is equivalent to `(window+"").indexOf('c')`. Notice that it does not make any sense to call `compose` on a single function, btw.

Comment: compose() is good for when you have functions that take one argument and return one value, like c=_.compose( alert, Function.call.bind([].pop), JSON.parse, unescape); c("%5B%22hello%22%5D")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Function composition is

```
  substr(indexOf(url))
= compose(substr, indexOf)(url)
```

what you need is an [Applicative](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land#applicative) actually which features

```
  substr(url, indexOf(url)) // actually substr(url)(indexOf(url))
= ap(substr, indexOf)(url)
```

Luckily, implementations for that [exist already](https://github.com/bergus/F/blob/fcb0ae1dc5528011557883e968087a895632a2a4/Function.js#L197), let's go with

```
function ap(f, g) {
    return function() {
        return f.apply(this, arguments)(g.apply(this, arguments));
    };
}
```

Next, we need a way to turn the methods of `String.prototype` into functions, like they already [exist in Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#String_generic_methods). We can use [bindbind](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13504936/1048572) for that purpose, which also has the benefit of returning (partially) curried functions.

```
var substr = Function.prototype.bind.bind(String.prototype.substr);
var indexOf = Function.prototype.bind.bind(String.prototype.indexOf);
```

You would use them like `indexOf("abcd")("c")` or `substr("abcd")(2)` now. Last but not least we need to flip the arguments of `indexOf`, so that we could use it like `flippedIndexOf("c")("abcd")` (and more importantly, get the `flippedIndexOf("c")` function on its own). So let's use

```
function flip(f) {
    return function(b) {
        return function(a) {
            return f(a)(b);
        };
    };
}
```

Now, we can do what you initially wanted:

```
var c = ap(substr, flip(indexOf)("?"));
```

Looks good, and actually works!

---

But probably this is not worth all the hazzle. Just go with

```
function c(url) { return url.substr(url.indexOf('?')); }
```

which everybody understands even if he has no Computer Science degree :-)